# Spring Boot Transactions not working

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

If I write interface for repository and implement CrudRepository, then there is no problem with persisting the data.

But If I don't use CrudReposity and write my own implementation, data fetch works fine but When i save data i get below exception..

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:275)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.persist(Unknown Source)
at com.eorganiser.commons.repositories.generic.SimpleJpaGenericRepository.persist(SimpleJpaGenericRepository.java:48)
at com.eorganiser.commons.repositories.generic.SimpleJpaGenericRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$12bdea51.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 56 common frames omitted
```

Below is the base dao which i wrote..

Interface JPAGenericRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * A generic dao which could be implememnted by all other daos
 * Created by piyush.kl on 21/10/15.
 */
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface JpaGenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    /**
     * persist the entity
     * @param entity
     */
    void persist(T entity);

    /**
     * persist a list of entities
     * @param entities, a {@link java.util.List} of entities
     */
    void persist(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

    /**
     * merge the changes of an existing entity.
     * @param entity
     * @return merged entity
     */
    <S extends T> S merge(S entity);

    /**
     * merge the changes of an existing entity.
     * @param entities, a {@link java.util.List} of entities
     * @return merged entities
     */
    <S extends T> Iterable<S> merge(Iterable<S> entities);

    /**
     * fetch all available entities from table.
     * @return a {@link java.util.List} of entities
     */
    List<T> findAll();

    /**
     * fetch a page of entities from table.
     * @param pageRequest, consisting a page number and size of the page.
     * @return a {@link java.util.List} of entities
     */
    Page<T> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest);

    /**
     * fetch a page of entities from table.
     * @param queryName, named query name
     * @param parameters, a map of keyword to replace in the query
     * @param pageRequest, , consisting a page number and size of the page.
     * @return, a page of entities
     */
    Page<T> findAllByNamedQuery(String queryName,
                                       Map<String, Object> parameters,
                                       PageRequest pageRequest);

    /**
     * fetch all the entities from table which satisfy the named query.
     * @param queryName, named query name
     * @param parameters, a map of keyword to replace in the query
     * @return a {@link java.util.List} of entities
     */
    List<T> findAllByNamedQuery(String queryName,
                                Map<String, Object> parameters);

    /**
     * fetch single entity with given named query and parameters
     * @param queryName, named query name
     * @param parameters, a map of keyword to replace in the query
     * @return an {@link java.util.Optional} object which represents 0 or 1 entity
     */
    Optional<T> findOneByNamedQuery(String queryName,
                                           Map<String, Object> parameters);

    /**
     * fetch entity with its Id
     * @param id, Id of the entity
     * @return an {@link java.util.Optional} object which represents 0 or 1 entity
     */
    Optional<T> findOne(ID id);

    /**
     * delete an entity
     * @param t, an entity
     */
    void delete(T t);

    /**
     * delete all the given entities
     * @param entities, a {@link java.util.List} of entities
     */
    void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities);

}
```

Implementation:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
@Data
public class SimpleJpaGenericRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        implements JpaGenericRepository<T, ID> {

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public SimpleJpaGenericRepository(Class clazz){
        this.entityClass = clazz;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void persist(T t) {
        getEntityManager().persist(t);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void persist(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
        for (T entity : entities) {
            persist(entity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public <S extends T> S merge(S entity) {
        return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public <S extends T> Iterable<S> merge(Iterable<S> entities) {
        List<S> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (S entity : entities) {
            result.add(merge(entity));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("select x from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " x")
                .getResultList();
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Page<T> findAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        Long count = (Long) getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("select count(x) from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " x")
                .getSingleResult();
        List<T> content = getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("select x from " + entityClass.getSimpleName() + " x")
                .setFirstResult(pageRequest.getOffset())
                .setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize())
                .getResultList();

        boolean hasMore = pageRequest.getPageSize() == content.size();
        return new Page<T>(count, content, hasMore);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Page<T> findAllByNamedQuery(String queryName, Map<String, Object> parameters,
                                       PageRequest pageRequest) {
        TypedQuery<T> countQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName + ".count", entityClass);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            countQuery.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        Long count = (Long) countQuery
                .getSingleResult();

        TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName, entityClass);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        List<T> content = query
                .setFirstResult(pageRequest.getOffset())
                .setMaxResults(pageRequest.getPageSize())
                .getResultList();

        boolean hasMore = pageRequest.getPageSize() == content.size();
        return new Page<T>(count, content, hasMore);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<T> findAllByNamedQuery(String queryName, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        TypedQuery<T> countQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName + ".count", entityClass);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            countQuery.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<T> findOneByNamedQuery(String queryName, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(queryName, entityClass);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
            query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        try {
            return Optional.of((T) query.getSingleResult());
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Optional<T> findOne(ID id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id));
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(T t) {
        getEntityManager().remove(t);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Iterable<? extends T> entities) {
        for (T entity : entities) {
            delete(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class JobServicesRepository extends SimpleJpaGenericRepository<JobServices, Long>{

    public JobServicesRepository(){
        super(JobServices.class);
    }

}
```

I have also annotated my service's public method with spring's Transactional annotation.

I am using Spring boot 1.2.7-ReLEASE, JERSEY and mysql.

Comment: You don't need a custom implementation. If it doesn't work you are probably doing too much configuration yourself or too little. Add you r configuration and/or application class and please remove the implementation as that basically beats the whole point using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I have few questions:
1. what if I want to use my custom implementation or if I had 2 datasource...??
2. Which way is better ?? to use custom implementation or interface one ?? Does spring boot uses reflection APIs to provide implementation at the time of container initialization or when required .. If second one is correct, would it not increase the response time..??
3. I saw someone using the custom implementation and it was working..

Comment: Of course you can use your custom implementation but in your case it doesn't add anything and basically beats the purpose of Spring Data JPA. I you have multiple datasource define multiple `@EnableJpaRepository` annotations. All your questions are answered in the Spring Data JPA reference guide.